# Did any SG teams ever get immediately targeted and attacked when they just strolled into an offworld town while covered in weapons?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Don't get me wrong, I love this series, but lately when I rewatch an episode I'm often struck by the arrogance (and seeming carelessness) of the SG teams just marching in on a village, or town, or even small city, and just assuming that either no one will care that they're heavily armed... or that everyone will be too scared to do anything about it.

My question is--did the SG Teams ever get called on this? Did the local guardsmen or police or security forces ever stand their ground and simply demand that these strangers either leave or surrender their weapons, and have it stick?

Because I know Jack O'Neill outright refused such orders more than once, and the people would back down, but I can't recall a situation where this very rational and normal concern was enforced.

I guess I feel like a team sent to scout out a strange culture should be a little more discreet about such things, rather than do the equivalent of rolling into a medium-sized Ohio town while waving shotguns and juggling hand grenades.

As a sidebar that I suppose would affect my feelings on this--Were guns treated so casually in, say, 17th century England or Europe? Would a town have been unconcerned if a group of heavily-armed strangers just rolled in and dared anyone to object to their weapons?

Comment: Most of the natives didn't seem to recognise the guns *as guns* since they were largely used to seeing staffs and zats

Comment: In 17th century England, most travelers would have been armed

Comment: Great question as the hypocritical part is they wouldn't wander around Earth in full camo and weapon gear. Yet most of the cities they visited they were all in full on Rambo clobber.  As you say Jack would always say 'Over my dead body' or similar if asked to submit his weapon. However there were a few occasions were the towns folk asked them to remove their weapons.

Answer (score 9):

[The Nox](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Nox) enforce their no guns rule in the first season. Of course, every time the team gets captured the weapons are taken as well. [The Tollans](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Shades_of_Grey) have a device that disables weapons too. I think there were some more times were a technological superior civilization did that.

Otherwise it is as the comments and your guess already stated. If someone else with seemingly heavy weapons rolls into town and doesn't start shooting around. Keep your head down and play nice. In 17th century Europe the usual populace certainly wasn't armed enough to enforce anything. Most of the time the guard or whatever precursor of modern police existed wasn't either.